# Updating custom CSS to latest Angular Material version

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular7

**Scenario:**

- I have an application which was using Angular 2 and Angular Material.
- I updated the project to Angular 7 and latest Material version using
  [update guide](https://update.angular.io/) and `ng update`.

**Problem:**

- The problem is I was relying on some
  of the CSS the old Material theme that inserted into the page automatically. 
  For example old CSS had `.mat-card-header { height:
  40px }` which doesn't seem to exist in new Card CSS.
- Angular Material
  still adds some CSS to the page but this height value is not there.

  - What should I do now?
  - Should I re-design my project's CSS from ground
    up 
    using new Material themes as a base, or
  - should I add the CSS I was
    using into the new project and make them all `!important` 
     so new Material
    CSS can't overwrite them or something?

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: No doubt, some components may have been changed internally, but the v7 card still uses `.mat-card-header`. I think you will have to be specific about what you are doing (global style or component style, ...) to get any useful help - actual code samples would be necessary, preferably a working (not working) StackBlitz example.

Comment: problem, we had to update all our css's, another option is not to update the material version